# rename file instead of directory in filepath

Tags: file-rename

I want to rename I file that is a variable but I am having problems.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/foo/fooYes/
$ touch ~/foo/fooYes/fooYes.txt
$ OUTPUT=~foo/fooYes/fooYes.txt
$ echo $OUTPUT
~/foo/fooYes/fooYes.txt
$ rename 's/fooYes/fooNo/' "${OUTPUT}"
Can't rename '/Users/medialab/foo/fooYes/fooYes.txt' to '/Users/medialab/foo/fooNo/fooYes.txt': No such file or directory
```

two questions:

Why is it telling me I can't rename?

More importantly, I want to rename fooYes.txt, NOT its parent directory.

I am using the simplified example above as a fill in for a shell script I have where "${OUTPUT}" is the result of an ffmpeg command. I want to rename the basename of "${OUTPUT}" but since it shares the same name as its parent directory (minus the extension, of course) it is the parent directory and not "${OUTPUT}" that gets renamed.

Comment: you seem to have made directory `fooYes`, but  not `fooNo`; you are trying to copy to a non-existent directory. `'/Users/medialab/foo/fooNo/fooYes.txt': No such file or directory`

Comment: Try to use the mv command (move) instead of rename

Comment: @Mike76 will mv allow me to rename a variable?

Comment: I think with variable, you just mean a path string variable, of course this is possible

Comment: Ok. I do. But I'm unsure how to do this. @Mike76

Comment: Just like this: mv $source $output

Comment: If do not see a use for the parenthesis {}

Comment: the curly braces are just how I'm used to writing. I think I'm not explaining myself well. if $source=~/foo/fooXYZABC/fooXYZABC.txt and I want $output to be ~/foo/fooXYZABC/fooABCABC.txt I'm not clear how to write that with variables. This is a script I will be running on hundreds of files with different names. @Mike76

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also:

```
mv file1 file2
```

Comment: how would I do when file1 is a variable and I only want to change part of its name?

Comment: you can use shell script to do it.

Comment: yes this is going to all be part of a shell script where "${OUPUT} is the result of an ffmpeg command. I then want to rename "${OUTPUT} but I'm having the problem that I simplified above.

Comment: you should remove the curly braces from output($OUTPUT only).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/foo/fooYes/
touch ~/foo/fooYes/fooYes.txt
OUTPUT=~/foo/fooYes/fooYes.txt
echo $OUTPUT
PARENTDIR=$(dirname $OUTPUT)
echo $PARENTDIR
cd $PARENTDIR
rename 's/fooYes/FooNo/' *.txt
cd ~
shift
```

Not very elegant but it does exactly what I want. If anyone has a better solution please share!